# Google Cloud Storage performance and full-text search

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, storage

I'm developing an application that servers data to the users (like we all, right?). It's crucial for the data to be full-text searchable. For now, we store over 30 million records, some of them searchable only on one field but some of them searchable on a few fields.

I'm considering Google cloud solutions, but I'm very new to their storage technology. Googling the full-text search for their cloud brings results like: "it's experimental", "there are some workarounds" etc.

Could someone from hers/his own experience tell me what it possible and what is the performance of full-text search in Google Could Storage solutions?

Thx in advance,
trzewiczek

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, full-text search for appengine (and Google Cloud Storage) isn't available yet.

There is a blog post here about it:
http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/10/app-engine-155-sdk-release.html

And a form here to register your interest, but you have to have a proper app to apply it to:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dEdWcnRJUXZ2VGR3YmVsT1Q1WVB2Smc6MQ&ndplr=1

To at least try and answer your question though, like, it's Google, so it's gonna be fast isn't it? They have been holding it back for a long time, presumably because it's not up to the task yet, but hopefully that will turn out to be a good thing in the long run.